# VueJS props are undefined in component

Tags: javascript, django, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to integrate VueJS with my frontend for my Django applications. I have the following Vue code in a javascript file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    Vue.component('discuss-post', {
        props: ['post'],
        template:  `<div class="card">
                        <div class="grid-x margin-x">
                            <div class="cell small-4">
                                <img class="avatar-img" :src="post.by.profile.img_url">
                                <p style="font-family: Abel;font-size: 24px">{{ post.by }}</p>
                            </<div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-x margin-x">
                            <div class="cell small-4">
                                <p style="font-family: Abel;font-size: 18px">{{ post.content }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
    })
    var postDiv = new Vue({
        el: "#post-div"
    })
}
```

And the following code in an HTML file:

```
            <div class="card-section">
                {% for feed in feeds %}
                {% for post in feed %}
                <div id="post-div">
                    <discuss-post post="{{ post }}"></discuss-post>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

However, when I load my page I get these errors in my console:

[image]

What in my code could be causing these errors to be raised?

Comment: try   <discuss-post :post="post"></discuss-post> where :post is the property and "post" matches your data that is being passed to your component.

Comment: That doesn't work, and it also causes me to get an additional error.

Comment: Whatever the additional error is, it definitely needs to be `:post="post"` not `:post="{{ post }}"`

Comment: <img class="avatar-img" :src="post.by.profile.img_url">，you access post.by.profile, you need to check the post.by whether exists or not.

Comment: @thanksd It has to be `{{ post }}` because I'm passing in a Django template variable as the property. Or at least I think so.

Comment: @JiangangXiong I know that it exists because I had console code that prints out the `post` variable and it prints out the proper information. It's not undefined. Furthermore, in the version of my frontend without VueJS, these variables work seamlessly.

Comment: <div class="cell small-4">
                                <img class="avatar-img" :src="post.by.profile.img_url">
                                <p style="font-family: Abel;font-size: 24px">{{ post.by }}</p>
                            </<div>    The last `</<div>` tag error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For compiling template error remove/fix this tag:`</<div>`.
Also, you have to pass props to the subcomponent like this:

`<discuss-post :post="post"></discuss-post>`

For your profile value error, you have to check your JSON structure in data.

See the following example:

```js
Vue.component('discuss-post', {
  props: ['post'],
  template: `<div class="card">
                     <div class="grid-x margin-x">
                       <div class="cell small-4">
                         <img class="avatar-img" :src="post.by.profile.img_url" />
                         <p style="font-family: Abel;font-size: 24px">{{ post.by }}</p>
                       <div>
                     </div>
               <div class="grid-x margin-x">
                 <div class="cell small-4">
                   <p style="font-family: Abel;font-size: 18px">{{ post.content }}</p>
                 </div>
               </div>
          </div>`
})
var postDiv = new Vue({
  el: "#post-div",
  data: function() {
    return {
      post: {
        content: "Post Content",
        by: {
          profile: {
            img_url: "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-section">
  <div id="post-div">
    <discuss-post :post="post"></discuss-post>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Isn't the information clear enough? What is **`</<div>`** in your code?

On the other hand, use `v-bind` if you want to pass an object. `{{ }}` is for **text** interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

Correct the `</<div>` with `</div>` as stated in the  answer from @Leo
assuming you have an object "post" in your vue instance

you can bind it like

```
<discuss-post :post="post"></discuss-post>
```

your post must be something like

```
post ={ 
    "by":{
         "profile":
          {
           "img_url":"some url"
          }
         },
    "content":"some content" 
     };
```